# Download file, filename

Tags: marklogic

I would like to provide a browser with a file download where I set the filename using `XQuery`. In this example I set the filename to '**example.txt**'.

The output fiename is: '**docmaker**' and this is not what I want it to be.

What is the correct header configuration to accomplish this?

```
declare 
%roxy:params("ID=xs:number")
function strlf:get(
$context as map:map,
$params  as map:map
) as document-node()*
{
map:put($context, "output-types", "application/csv"),
map:put($context, "Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="example.txt"'),
xdmp:set-response-code(200, "OK"),
    document {
          try {
              let $id := map:get($params,"ID")

              let $query := 
                if (fn:empty($id)) 
                then ()
                else cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("jbasic:ID"),"=",(fn:number($id)))

                for $doc in cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-query((cts:directory-query("/app/docmaker/"),$query)), ('unfiltered'))

                return $doc//jbasic:Text/text()

          }
          catch ($e) {
            element error { $e/error:message }
          }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, the Content-Disposition header, nor any other custom header is supported from within REST extensions:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_84661

I don't see other ways around this either. The built-in documents endpoint doesn't provide a download feature of its own, and transforms go through the same framework, so that won't work either.

I'd recommend filing an RFE. That will probably not be helpful for you personally (you'll have to wait for one of the next releases), but may be useful for others in the future..

****UPDATE****

@mblakele's suggestion works, below a working example. I'm reluctant recommending it though. The add-response-header works, but the set-response-code doesn't. The REST-API will override it. The same could happen in future with the add-response-header call..

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace ext = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/download";

declare default function namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";

declare namespace roxy = "http://marklogic.com/roxy";
declare namespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

declare option xdmp:mapping "false";

declare
%roxy:params("ID=xs:number")
function ext:get(
  $context as map:map,
  $params  as map:map
) as document-node()*
{
  map:put($context, "output-types", "application/csv"),
  xdmp:add-response-header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="example.txt"'),
  xdmp:set-response-code(300, "OK"),
  document {
    try {
      doc()[1]
    } catch ($e) {
      element error { $e/error:message }
    }
  }
};
```

HTH!

Comment: The key difference is there's only one response code and the REST API will often want to set it. But the REST API is unlikely to set `Content-Disposition` on its own.

Comment: No signs pointing that way, but it could be that REST extensions will get executed in an entirely different way in future. Such different that directly interacting with the response won't be possible anymore for instance. Not likely soon, but you never know. It would be better if the REST api would support adding response headers throught $context, hence the suggestion to file an RFE. And the more people do so, the more likely it gets added soon..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `map:put`, try calling [https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:add-response-header](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3aadd-response-header) directly. There's probably no need to set the response code: it should default to `200 OK` unless there's an error.

I'm not sure exactly how roxy handles that `$context` item, but I don't see any code that would transform it into response headers automatically.

Comment: It is actually a plain REST-API extension. The Roxy annotation is just helping Roxy to deploy it with the correct parameter information. The handling of `$context` is not done by Roxy, but by the REST-API of MarkLogic itself..

Comment: That said, xdmp:add-response-header does work, though it is kind of bypassing the framework that the REST-API is imposing. No guarantee that it will keep working in future either, unfortunately..

Comment: I think it's safe enough. The reason the REST API overwrites the response code is that it calls `xdmp:set-response-code` itself. If and when the REST API provides a mechanism to call `xdmp:add-response-header` it probably won't overwrite headers already set by other code. You'd only have to worry about headers that the REST API might want to set on its own: perhaps ETag or Content-Type.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a Roxy app, not sure if thats using the ML Rest extensions.
I would post a question to the Roxy site ...

http://developer.marklogic.com/code/roxy

Or to the MarkLogic general mailing list.

MarkLogic Developer Discussion

Roxy is a developer product not a official MarkLogic product.

If writing a "pure" HTTP App then your technique would work.  I dont know what other features of Roxy you need, can you make this particular endpoint a pure HTTP endpoint without changing the rest ?

Comment: It is actually a plain REST-API extension. The Roxy annotation is just helping Roxy to deploy it with the correct parameter information.