# How to set file name for downloaded csv result in rest extension?

Tags: marklogic

I have a  rest extension that Puts a request for a calculation that results in a document.The GET will download the text element of the document as a csv.

UPDATE: see comment in code
UPDATE 2: 
updated code includes lines that throw error
the POST will store a document that holds the filename also
strlf:get-file-name($id) function gives back the filename(tested and works by itself)

UPDATE 3 see working example below!

```
declare 
%roxy:params("ID=xs:number")
function strlf:get(
  $context as map:map,
  $params  as map:map
) as document-node()*
{

    (: this does not work and gives ERROR
    let $id := map:get($params,"ID")
    let $filename := strlf:get-file-name($id)
    :)
    map:put($context, "output-types", "application/csv"),
    xdmp:add-response-header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="lijst.csv"'),
    xdmp:set-response-code(300, "OK"),
    document {
              try {
                  let $id := map:get($params,"ID")

                  let $query := 
                    if (fn:empty($id)) 
                    then ()
                    else cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("jbasic:ID"),"=",(fn:number($id)))

                    for $doc in cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-query((cts:directory-query("/app/vertaler/"),$query)), ('filtered'))

                    return $doc/jbasic:json/jbasic:Text/text()


              }
              catch ($e) {
                element error { $e/error:message }
              }
    }
};
```

Now my question: How do I change the default filename "lijst.csv" of the attachement to have a custom file name each time i call the API (including a count of the number of lines in the csv for example so "lijst-123.csv" if there are 123 rows)?

Actually the filename is already present in the document, seems I cannot set it in the header dynamically?

ERROR when deploying extension:

```
ERROR: 400 "Bad Request"
ERROR: <rapi:error xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api"><rapi:status-code>400</rapi:status-code><rapi:status>Bad Request</rapi:status><rapi:message-code>RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT</rapi:message-code><rapi:message>RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid vertaler extension: could not parse XQuery extension vertaler; please see the server error log for detail XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected QName_; vertaler either is not a valid module or does not provide extension functions (delete, get, put, post) in the http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/vertaler namespace</rapi:message></rapi:error>
```

WORKING SOLUTION:

```
declare 
%roxy:params("ID=xs:number")
function strlf:get(
  $context as map:map,
  $params  as map:map
) as document-node()*
{


    map:put($context, "output-types", "application/csv"),

    let $id := map:get($params,"ID")
    let $fn := strlf:get-file-name($id)
    return xdmp:add-response-header("Content-Disposition", fn:concat('attachment; filename="',$fn,'"')),
    xdmp:set-response-code(300, "OK"),
    document {
              try {
                  let $id := map:get($params,"ID")

                  let $query := 
                    if (fn:empty($id)) 
                    then ()
                    else cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("jbasic:ID"),"=",(fn:number($id)))

                    for $doc in cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:and-query((cts:directory-query("/app/vertaler/"),$query)), ('filtered'))

                    return $doc/jbasic:json/jbasic:Text/text()


              }
              catch ($e) {
                element error { $e/error:message }
              }
    }
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download file, filename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606676/download-file-filename)

Comment: is similar but not duplicate, my problem is I cannot add code before the xdmp:add-response-header as soon as I add any code it cannot be depoyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
let $count := xdmp:estimate(cts:search(...))
return
    xdmp:add-response-header("Content-Disposition", fn:concat('attachment; filename="list', $count, '.csv"'))
```

*UPDATE*

You attempt seems to be missing a return statement that needs to follow the let statements. Note that the commas are separating the statements within the function. I suggest moving the lets one line down (to below the first map:put), and then adding 'return' after them, roughly like this:

```
map:put($context, "output-types", "application/csv"),

let $id := map:get($params,"ID")
let $filename := strlf:get-file-name($id)
return
    xdmp:add-response-header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="lijst.csv"'),

...
```

HTH!

Comment: see update as soon as i add the "let $count := ..." I cannot deploy the extension...

Comment: Please provide the accurate line that gives mentioned error. It reports a syntax error. Take particularly close attention to the single and double quotes. It is easy to mess those up. The lines I provide above should work if you fill in the dots..

Comment: thx updated question to hold solution, muchios gratias senor!